# URL Rewrite to New Directory & New Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

We are trying to rewrite a URL folder directory as well as the domain name via .htaccess. Can someone give me an example of this?

example.com/folder1/
to
example2.com/folder1/folder2/

Comment: please give more details to your question!

Comment: Need a combination of Rewrite Rule & Redirect possibly in HTACCESS. Trying to acheive. example1.com/folder1/ rewrites & redirects to example2.com/folder1/folder2/